# Skewed 3d model when moving device around with Unity and Vuforia

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am having trouble with the orientation of a 3d model that is larger (think queen-sized bed) than the target image(a4 size bond paper). The model appears to be slanted in a way that looks totally unrealistic especially when moving the device around. Is there a way to keep the model horizontally aligned with the real-world floor?

I have already enabled Extended Tracking but the behavior is still present. I have also set the world center to Specific Target and set Device Camera focus mode to `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO`.

Thank you.